# If $G$ has no proper subgroups then $G$ is cyclical with order $p$, prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

If $G$ has no proper-nontrivial subgroups then $G$ is cyclical with order $p$, prime.

I already proved that $G$ is cyclical.

If the order of $G=\langle g\rangle $ is $ab,$ with $1<a<ab$, then $g^{ab}=1,$  then $(g^b)^a=1$ then $\langle g^b\rangle $ has order $a<ab$, and this subgroup is proper (contradiction)

Comment: Technically, the statement is false, since the trivial group $G=\{e\}$ has no proper subgroups, but does not have prime order.

Comment: Take a non-identity element $g$.  if it doesn't generate the whole group then you have a proper subgroup, if it has composite order divisible by prime $q$ then look at $\langle g^q \rangle$, finally if the order is infinite then look at $\langle g^2 \rangle$.